# How can I make a custom grid inside a CollectionViewCell using autolayout?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionViewCell` in which I want to display some `UIButtons` with in some **custom grid**, like this:

[image: Cell example]

As you can see I have different kind of arrangements for the grid, I actually have these possibles types of arrangements that depends on the data I have:

[image: Types of grid]

I'm trying to know how to accomplish this, I don't know what's the best way to have this **different types of grid arrangements** inside the `cell`. One first though was to make a different `UICollectionCiewCell` for each arrangement but since there's also other `views` inside the cell like the white rounded view, the title and the subtitle, I think that's not the best way to solve this. Then I though about using `XIB` files or maybe a `ContainerView` but I really don't know what's the best way to do this.

But the **biggest problem** here is also how to **set the constraints** for this type of view, I was trying with the constraints in storyboard but that didn't help a lot, maybe I should set the constraints programmatically or maybe even do a `XIB` file for each arrangement and each device haha.

This is what I had in my `Storyboard` that didn't work as I though:

[image: Autolayout in storyboard]

All the buttons are inside a view with a constraint of aspect ratio, bottom, left and right constraint to 11 each one.

I have the buttons with aspect ratio constraint, the red views are just spacer views with width or height of 2 as a constraint, and all the buttons have top, left, right and bottom constraint to 0 with its closer view.
But as I said before this **didn't work** well.

Please comment or answer any idea or question you have.

Comment: You want to have the grid inside a cell? Or du you want arrange cells in a collection view in a grid?

Comment: It's not clear to me if each `UICollectionViewCell` is an individual `UIButton` or if each collection of `UIButton`s is a single different `UICollectionViewCell` (and there are 10 types of cells). If it's the first one, then you need to create a custom collection view layout that can return the correct info for each `UICollectionViewCell`.

Comment: @RoboticCat @vikingosegundo  I update the first image to the question to explain myself better. It's a `UICollectionViewCell` that has a `UIView` that has the `UIButtons`